# Remember password alert

Tags: php, html, forms

This is more of an annoyance than a problem, but on all the login forms I have created over the years, none of them have ever asked the user in the browser if they want to remember password, what am I not doing?

Comment: You should rephrase the question... Are you saying that you want to know how to implement the remember password feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked and found out that it was in fact only some of my login forms that weren't doing the remember password mambo. I discovered that the difference was the id field being different to the name field on the password input is the key, i.e.

```
<label for="password">Password</label>

         <input name="password" type="password"  id="password" />
```

Doesn't work

But

```
<label for="pass">Password</label>

         <input name="password" type="password"  id="pass" />
```

Does

Answer (score 0):

Your form is using `autocomplete="off"` on the login inputs.

Remembering passwords (client side) is a function of the browser. There's nothing you need to do to trigger it. However, the `autocomplete` tags will turn it off. Simply remove them.